# very simple application ( increment and decrement a seven segment display using 2 buttons)

Tags: c

i wrote a simple program to increment and decrement the value on 7 segment display using 2 buttons , and when i tried to try it on atmega16 microcontroller only the increment worked , the decrement part works only if i tried to increment first otherwise it doesn't work , also if the number reaches 0 it doesn't go to 9 .. i'm sure there's something wrong with the code but i can't figure it out.
Here's the code

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<util/delay.h>

int main()
{


//seven seg display  PORTC 0:3 , initial value 2 , inc when Port B6 is pressed (dont   exceed 9>>0) , dec Port B7
//init
//set DDRC 0:3 as output    
DDRC |=0x0F;
//set init value for 7 seg as 2
PORTC &= 0xF0;
PORTC |=(1<<1);

//set port B 6,7 as inputs
DDRB &=0x3F;



while(1)
{
    //check if b6 is pressed
    if(!(PINB & 0b01000000))
    {
        _delay_ms(30);
        while(!(PINB & 0b01000000));
        if((PORTC & 0x0F) ==0x09)
            {
                PORTC &= 0xF0;
            }
        else
            {
                PORTC= PORTC++;
            }

    }
    if(!(PINB & 0b10000000))
    {
        _delay_ms(30);
        while(!(PINB & 0b10000000));
        if((PORTC & 0x0F) ==0x00)
            {
                PORTC &= 0xF9;
            }
        else
            {
                PORTC= PORTC--;
            }

    }
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: `PORTC= PORTC++;` is wrong: "altering PORTC twice without an intervening sequence point". (similar for `PORTC= PORTC--;` )

Comment: Please expand on what have you tried to debug it so far. This is not code review, if we have an indication where you are stuck we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PORTC &= 0xF9;` will not change 0 to 9. In fact, it does nothing when PORTC is 0.

Also, get rid of `PORTC= PORTC++;` and `PORTC= PORTC--;` constructions, they are incorrect. Either use `PORTC++;`, or `PORTC = PORTC + 1;`.